# video player is full screen but video is smaller than it

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

hi I am using flutter with SDK version 2.12 I used video_player and better_player widget in my project when I build my app and use it on android box with android version 6.0.1 the video player is full screen but the video in it is smaller than it
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JnB6.jpg)

what should I do for this problem

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  validators: ^1.0.0+1
  http: ^0.12.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  connectivity: ^2.0.1
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
  video_player: ^2.1.0
  better_player: ^0.0.63
  package_info: ^0.4.0+17
```

video player page codes

```dart
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Videoplayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String streamkey;


  Videoplayer({this.streamkey, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoplayerState createState() => _VideoplayerState();


}

class _VideoplayerState extends State<Videoplayer> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      child: BetterPlayer.network(

        "http://{{some ip}}/vod/mp4:${widget.streamkey}/manifest.mpd",

        betterPlayerConfiguration: BetterPlayerConfiguration(
          aspectRatio: 4/3,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          autoPlay: true,
          autoDispose: true,
          fullScreenByDefault: false,
          autoDetectFullscreenDeviceOrientation: true,


        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any updates to this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can get rid of it if you try "chewie" instead of "better_player".

here
https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

Comment: But better_player is an upgrade of chewie ‍♂️

Comment: Yes it is, but chewie seems to handle aspect ratio better.